# how to load phtml file with variables assigned in a php file

Tags: html, php, email-templates

I am trying to load or get all the content from phtml in a php file

everything is working fine except the variables in phtml file are not loading with values

Here is my php file

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$code = rand(11111,99999);
$emailSubject = 'Email Verification';
$userEmail = 'some@some.com';

function loadEmailTemplate($pagelink='') {

$page = 'email-templates/' . $pagelink . '.phtml';
$pageContent = '';

ob_start();
include($page);
$pageContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $pageContent;
}

$mailBody = loadEmailTemplate('emailtemplate');

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: no-reply-some@some.com\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
mail($userEmail, $emailSubject, $mailBody, $headers);
?>
```

and my emailtemplate.phtml is

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color: #bb4e4e; width:80%; color: #fff;">
 Thank you for registering <?php echo $firstname; ?>, your verification code is <?php echo $code; ?>.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my output in email or if i echo $mailBody is

```
 Thank you for registering <?php echo $firstname; ?>, your verification code is <?php echo $code; ?>.
```

but my output should be

```
Thank you for registering John, your verification code is 52256.
```

it means phtml file is loading fine but i want to load the variable values defined in php file, i thought we are loading the content of phtml file after defining php variables which will allot the variable values automatically but it is not, i am wrong. can some please help me in finding any way for this.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Apache to process those files like `php`.

Add:

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

To your apache config or `.htaccess` file

For more information, please read: https://php.net/manual/ro/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: still it is not loading the values

Comment: If you're not using `require_once` (or similar), they are not defined yet (different HTTP request, different context). Try passing them to the session: `$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname` in your first file, and echo that in the phtml

Comment: In order to use session variables, you need to start the session in the phtml as well:  `if(!session_id()) session_start();`

Comment: your idea of sessions is working, thank you. though i did nt add that code in htaccess, phtml is working

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem you should just need to add global definitions in your phtml file.

Here is what your phtml should look like

```
<?php global $firstname, $lastname; ?>
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color: #bb4e4e; width:80%; color: #fff;">
 Thank you for registering <?php echo $firstname; ?>, your verification code is <?php echo $code; ?>.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```